# Octopus Component Tester Analysis

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, components

I'm a beginner in electronics and my knowledge is pretty basic. I've been trying to understand how the Octopus Component Tester Works. I know that it's outputs should be used to plot a Current x Voltage relation in an oscilloscope, but I don't understand why we use the resistor's current and not that of the actual component that is being tested. I also don't really know how to analyse circuits where the voltage is varying. I would be really grateful if someone could explain how does it work. Here's the diagram:

[image]

The probes in the diagram are where the component to be tested should be attached to.

Comment: Testing octopus components??  Just tap the component.  If it tries to hold on, its a leg.  If not, its a head.

Comment: I believe we used to call this a "curve tracer" in the olden days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I've never heard of this circuit before, I watched the video @user23711 linked. I think I can give you a decent explanation.

Essentially, you have an AC source driving your device with a resistor in series acting as a current limiter. The voltage measurement is simple. You are literally just measuring the voltage across the device under test, just like any other voltage measurement with an oscilloscope or multimeter.

As for current, you are measuring the voltage across the resistor and not the device under test (DUT) because voltage is (sort of) proportional to current in a resistor. Since the resistor is in series with the DUT, the current is the same as that of the DUT. However, the voltage across the resistor will be proportional to the current while the voltage of the DUT has an unknown relationship to current. That is, after all, the purpose of this circuit.

Now, if you had a current probe for your scope, you wouldn't need this test setup. Also, be mindful that the V/I curve for a resistor is not perfectly linear. If you are looking for high accuracy this might not be the way to go.

Finally, the reason for the AC source is to frequently enough cycle the voltage of the DUT. Then, when using XY mode on the scope, the IV curve of the DUT can be seen. But really, you could use any source you want (that won't break the DUT), and view the voltage and current curves with respect to time.

Comment: Years (and a whole graduation in Electronic Engineering) later, I thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: Ha! Congrats! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video.  Very explanatory.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gwo3pEH7hUE

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Definitely better than no answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an very old thread but I recently stumbled over this device in multiple youtube videos like w2eaw above or Mr. Carlson's Lab and then looked here for an opinion.

I did some tests and it does work reasonably well.
It is basically a voltage divider between the current sensing resistor and the DUT if you unwrap the sometimes confusing schematics.

Depending on the lowest range on your oscilloscope and the used test voltage it will work between 100 Ohms and 1MOhm or 1uF - 10pf respectively.. (@60Hz)
(I used 5V AC and a 5K resistor)

BUT:  There are some very confusing claims that float around with these circuits:

1. You can use it in circuit: (that would be really nice)
   How?  If you use it in-circuit you always will measure
   the Thevenin equivalent at these nodes, not the single        part. Maybe you can detect a short or open...
2. "It is save to use in-circuit..."
   Mmmh...
   There are several caveats here.

   First, you are using AC, if you measure (accidentally or not)
   across an IC input you will be testing its protection circuits in the negative range... Hopefully your voltage and current are not too high. (you might want to restrict your device to only using positive half waves and not accidentally reverse it)

Secondly: "It is safe because it is using less than one Volt..."
Alright.... If you do this you will restrict your useful range
quite a bit, also how do you test LEDs, Zener and/or transistor breakdown voltages as they are shown in the pretty pictures?

Thirdly: It is so quick.. Not sure.. Before I have started up my
scope and connected the wires, I probably can stick the DUT into
a $10 transistor/diode tester, or measure a resistor/capacitor     correctly with a meter.

Bottom line: Interesting device.. worth some playing and learning
but no really useful anymore. (maybe in the old days when transistor testers where expensive.

To make it work you would need some controls (voltage, polarity, current resistor..) to finally get a wiggly line on a scope that is hard to interpret.

Maybe that's the reason that modern scopes don't have this feature anymore ???

Just my opinion, but it was fun to play with it.